# I signed up, but I never received the confirmation email

Tags: support, accounts, email

I recently signed up on Stack Overflow, but I never received the confirmation email after signing up. I am using Gmail. I searched everywhere in my mailbox, but no email was found. It's very frustrating—please help!

Comment: The system seems to think you have had an account for nearly 2 years, and that you are currently logged into it. What sort of confirmation are you seeking? What are you still waiting to have happen?

Comment: I want to create a new account so I signed up with a different email address, after signing up a message appears on the screen telling me to check confirmation email in my mailbox  and that I should receive the message within 15 min. However, I didn't received any email after days.

Comment: You may want to use the 'contact us' link in the footer; you'll reach the *Community Management team*, a small group of employees that can handle things like checking logs and such. Give them your email details too, they'll handle that confidentially.

Comment: Do note that while creating additional accounts is not prohibited, using such accounts to do things you can't do with just one account is not permitted. This includes bypassing system limitations (such as rate limits or post bans).

Comment: Thanks a lot Martijin Pieters I will do so